# D3DXCreateTextureFromFile does not create texture

Tags: c++, directx-9

D3DXCreateTextureFromFile does not work for me, i get the D3DXERR_INVALIDDATA error when i use XorString and the D3DERR_INVALIDCALL when i don't.

```cpp
if (Globals::User::g_pAvatar == nullptr)
{
    auto s_avatarFile = Globals::g_sAppdataFolder + "\\avatar.jpg";
    auto avatarFile = s_avatarFile.c_str();

    if (!fileExists(avatarFile))
    {
        download(Globals::User::g_sAvatarUrl.c_str(), avatarFile);
        D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(Globals::g_pD3DDevice, XorStr(avatarFile), Globals::User::g_pAvatar);
    }
    else if (fileExists(avatarFile)) {
        HRESULT hr = D3DXCreateTextureFromFile(Globals::g_pD3DDevice, XorStr(avatarFile), Globals::User::g_pAvatar);
        switch (hr) {
        case D3D_OK:                            
            break;
        case D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE:
            MessageBox(0, "D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE", "dx9", MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONHAND);
            break;
        case D3DERR_OUTOFVIDEOMEMORY:
            MessageBox(0, "D3DERR_OUTOFVIDEOMEMORY", "dx9", MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONHAND);
            break;
        case D3DERR_INVALIDCALL:
            MessageBox(0, "D3DERR_INVALIDCALL", "dx9", MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONHAND);
            break;
        case D3DXERR_INVALIDDATA:
            MessageBox(0, "D3DXERR_INVALIDDATA", "dx9", MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONHAND);
            break;
        case E_OUTOFMEMORY:
            MessageBox(0, "E_OUTOFMEMORY", "dx9", MB_OKCANCEL | MB_ICONHAND);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a minimum reproducible example? See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: found and fixed the problem. it was because the file is a jpeg, it should be a png apparently

Comment: You can make an answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The D3DX9 library is very old, and it used the filename extension to determine which codec to use for loading the image. Since you told it `jpg` it will only try to load it using jpeglib.

The D3DX10 and D3DX11 libraries use Windows Imaging Component ([WIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-programming-guide)) which relies on a file inspection technique, so it wouldn't care what the physical file-name is. You can find a modern DDSTextureLoader, WICTextureLoader, and ScreenGrab for legacy DX9 [here](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex) which does not require D3DX9 at all.

D3DX9 includes codecs for BMP, JPG, PNG, TGA, HDR, and PPM/PFM. D3DX10/D3DX11 via WIC supports BMP, GIF, JPG, PNG, TIFF, and HDPhoto (JPEG-XR). They both included support for DDS as well.

> [DirectXTex](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTex) includes a codec for TGA and HDR because they are common source texture formats, but are not supported by any built-in WIC codec. The DirectXTex implementation of HDR recognizes both `?RADIANCE` and `?RGBE` headers, but D3DX9 only supported `?RADIANCE`.
>
> Note that D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11 are all deprecated (see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directx-sdk--august-2009-)) along with the DirectX SDK itself.